# Why % gets printed in half count in C?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
printf("% % % %");
}
```

For the above program, the output is % %. But why? (I used gcc compiler).

Comment: You might want to compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.

Comment: Please read [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) reference and esspecialy about its `format` parameter

Comment: @mvidelgauz It would be better to link to a C site though, right?

Comment: @machine_1 Yes you are right! But that page titled as "C++/C reference" ))

Comment: Here is the link to `C` documentation - http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Answer (score 5):

*Undefined behavior* is invoked by using invalid format specifier.

[N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function says in the description of `%` conversion specifier:

> The complete conversion specification shall be %%.

N1570 4. Conformance says:

> If a ‘‘shall’’ or ‘‘shall not’’ requirement that appears outside of a constraint or runtime-constraint is violated, the behavior is undefined.

The description of `%` conversion specifier is in "Description" section, not constraint nor runtime-constraint section.

In the actual implemention, the system's behavior seems like this:

1. Read first `%` and start parsing specifier
2. Read  and save it as a flag
3. Read second `%` and treat it as `%` conversion specifier
4. Read  after that and print it because it is not a part of specifier
5. Read `% %` and do work like 1-3

Comment: Ah, yes, ye old "undefined behavior" I wonder how much code depends on this.  Do the elevated warnings above catch this?  It's a run time error, technically, though static analysis at compile time is possible in this case.

Comment: I wouldn't try to rationalize this behavior, since a whitespace cannot be a flag, modifier, specifier. It's simply undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501 A whitespace is a flag that tell the system to print a whitespace as sign character for non-negative integers. For example, `% d` is a valid format specifier.

Comment: @MikeCAT Ah, you're right I missed that one. Still, standard says it must be `%%`, no whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

That is interesting.  the % % counts as %% somehow, huh.  Must be in the parsing rules for printf formats in the stdio library. In general "% " is not exactly a valid format specification.  %% %% %% %% would get you what you want.

Comment: It is the library and not the compiler at work here.

Comment: Quite true, fixed.